# ¿cómo puedo poner la entrada del usuario en una matriz?

Tags: java

Por mas que intento nada funciona:

cómo poner la entrada del usuario en una matriz

```
import java.util.random;
public class main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int [][] a = new int[100][100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; j++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 67; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

La pregunta por lo poco que comentas es que quieres rellenar una matriz, pero en tu código hay partes que no entiendo porque aparecen pero puedo suponerlo. Creas un Random pero luego realmente no lo usas.

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Luego para recorrer el array empiezas bien en la fila.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; j++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 67; j++) {
```

Pero para recorrer la columna en vez de indicar el tamaño de la matriz que inicializaste a 100 lo indicas como 67, eso haria que muchos campos se quedasen en `null`.

Si quieres rellena una matriz de 3x3 en estructura ibas bien, solo te faltaba completar los detalles. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo, el rellena la matriz con números aleatorios.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int [][] a = new int[100][100];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // Usamos .lenght, de esta forma si cambia el tamaño de la matriz esta parte seguira funcionando igualmente
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*100+1); // Usamos un Math.random para que en cada vuelta se genere un nuevo numero
            }
        }
        for (int x=0; x < a.length; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y < a[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.println ("[" + x + "," + y + "] = " + a[x][y]); // Visualizamos la matriz mostrando sus respectivas posiciones.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda si es esto lo que buscabas, sino indícalo y cambia la pregunta.